# Highchart bar chart handle over lapping data lables for series

Tags: highcharts

For this kind of chart here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/VbecE/22/). I want to keep the data labels for the every series on the chart. But I can't figure out how I can handle this overlapping issue.

First I was unable to see labels for every series, with this option   `allowOverlap: true` I can see lables but as they are overlapping. I can't figureout how to present chart in readable way.

```
bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                     allowOverlap: true,
                    crop: false
                }
            }
```

Comment: Relevant feature request: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/15960472-collision-detection-for-data-labels

Answer (score 0):

Move data labels using [dataLabels.y](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.dataLabels.y).

```
series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2],
        dataLabels: {
          y: -5
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 2008',
        data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34],
        dataLabels: {
          y: 4
        }
    }]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/VbecE/23/